# How do I accelerate all jquery animations?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, time

Suppose I've kicked off a bunch of animations with jQuery. How do I accelerate through these animations to test their side effects without waiting?

In other words. What would this magic `tick` function look like?

```
var el = $('selector');
log(el.css("left"));            // 10

el.animate({left:"-=5"}, 1000);

log(el.css("left"));            // ≈10
jQuery.tick(1000);              // accelerate
log(el.css("left"));            // 5
```

Simply mocking out the setInterval and setTimer doesn't seem to be enough.

**Update**

I accepted @jfriend00's answer for the direct hook into jquery's animation speed (awesome). For unit testing though, it should be enough to just turn off the fx engine. +1 for those answers!

Comment: Ask the user to flip the [turbo switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_button) :D

Comment: You mean, aside from using `.stop(false,true)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very first thing the existing animate function does is call `jQuery.speed()` to sort through the various argument options to `animate()` to figure out which is the speed and other options.  You could patch into that function and change the speed to a shorter value there.

```
jQuery.oldSpeed = jQuery.speed;
jQuery.speed = function() {
    var opt = jQuery.oldSpeed.apply(this, arguments);
    opt.duration = Math.floor(opt.duration / 10);
    return(opt);        
}
```

This wouldn't change an animation once it had already started, but would just cut the time for all animations.  Since many other animations (perhaps all of them) end up calling .animate() themselves, this should work with many other animations too.

You can see this work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6JUGu/.  After you press the "Go Faster" button, the next animation cycle will start with the faster speed.

Comment: +1 this is a pretty crafty solution. I should note this down. :D

Answer (score 2):

Under the pretext of **unit testing**, I'm assuming that you want to *skip all animations* but still keep their intended effects?

If that's what you want, you can just set `$.fx.off = true` and this will globally disable all jQuery animations from **tweening**, or animating, but they will all still go to their logical end. So `.animate()` becomes essentially the same as `.css()` because of the lack of animation.

If you're looking for something more modular, you can look at calling `.stop(bool,bool)` on your elements instead. Passing in `true` for the second argument, for example, stops the currently running animation on the selected elements **and** jumps to the animation's logical end.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd either have to set a multiplier on the time for each animation (probably not an option)

or you could set `$.fx.off = true;` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.off/) to immediately see the difference.  (you wouldn't see acceleration, just an instant change).

Comment: When I turn fx.off are animation calls synchronous?

Answer (score 0):

Or just reduce the duration to less than 1000? :)